# Grid floor disappears and cannot see outline of selected objects

Tags: interface, 3d-view, selection-tools

What did I do? I somehow changed my view setting and I can no longer select anything with RMB. Please see screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have ticked an option that displays only objects that will be rendered. Open the *Properties* panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and untick *Only Render* under *Display*. You *can* actually select objects (the 3d manipulator widget is still being shown) and move them as normal, you just cannot see the visible outline.

[image]

Comment: Did I hit a key command for that? Don't want to repeat.

Comment: @kjfagan No, there is no shortcut, you were probably poking around.

Comment: HUGE. Thank you so much. Yeah, probably hit it on accident.

Comment: @kjfagan feel free to accept the answer if it solve your problem. This will help future users.

Comment: @iKlsR, actually I think there is a shorcut (can't remember if I bind it myself, or if it's default): ALT + SHIFT + Z

Comment: @Polosson It's not in the keymaps and that doesn't work on my end. You probably binded it.

Answer (score 6):

The original question was asked in 2014, 7 years ago. Now we are on blender 2.91. The down arrow next to Overlays icon in upper right corner of 3d viewport  [image: down arrow next to Overlays icon in upper right corner of 3d viewport] produces this window [image: Overlays dropdown]. If **grid is checked and floor is unchecked**, what you see depends on the frontal vs top views and the orthographic vs perspective views.
Front ortho view **grid** 
Front perpective **no grid**
Top perspctive **no grid**
Top ortho         **grid**
If **grid is unchecked and floor is unchecked**
Front ortho **no grid**
Front perspective **no grid**
Top persective **no grid**
Top ortho **no grid**
If **grid is unchecked and floor is checked**
Front ortho **no grid**
Front perspective **no grid**
Top perspective **grid**
Top ortho no **grid**
If **grid is checked and floor is checked**
Front ortho  **grid**
Front perspective **no grid**
Top perspective **grid**
Top ortho **no grid**
I hope that is clear and I hope it helps future blender users

Answer (score 1):

Came here because my grid floor plane had disappeared as well.  Realized it was because the 3D viewport shading was set to "Render".  Changing it back to Solid fixed it.  Shift+Z

Answer (score 1):

In my instance, on Blender 2.80, I had to select "Grid" within the viewport overlays dropdown

[image: Viewport overlays]

Comment: And "Viewport Overlays" can be found from 3rd dropdown menu in top right corner of the viewport (icon looks like outline of circle overlapped with filled circle). As far as I can see, it cannot be accessed via normal menus nor context menus anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was viewing the 'Layout' view instead of the 'Modeling'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now. Make sure your clipping distance is set up to 0.001m-10000m.

I know this is a little late, but hopefully it'll help anyone else looking around.

Comment: Clipping distance of 0.001m-10000m will probably cause viewport rendering artifacts / z-fighting (if changed in viewport) due to too high range of values set for showing the geometry with that precision which isn't necessarily supported by some GPUs. Also viewport grid usually doesn't require too precise clipping values since it's just optional displaying tool for convenience

Answer (score 0):

With the Z Euler axes, you need to have the viewport render to options. This enables locks on the rotation and location, making the grids visible. If that doesn't work, make sure the Archimesh is set, and not the other way around. The face orientation won't matter unless your motion tracking is off. The X & Y axes have a certain way of moving, different from that of the Z, so facing the front will give it a slightly altered look. If still your grid is not visible, set the origins of each mesh (not light or other object) to center. This will most likely transform your grid, and then you can parent it to some object in your viewport. Display is also important. Go to the render zone when the rest of the steps are done, delete all keyframes. This done, your textures won't take up as much of the GPU, making space for your grid. The grid is actually the last thing your system will try and keep with everything else to take into account, and therefore it tends to disappear. Under options, selected should be location, because the grid is your location. If all else fails, close blender, restart your laptop, download the latest version of your PC

Answer (score 0):

Also, in my case I was in the wrong *Workspace* tab, *Shading*. Switching back to *Layout* got the grid back.

[image]